# Improve performance of DeleteDuplicates for list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-request

I have a matrix $A_0[x,y,z]$ and a list of matrices $B$ with about 30 matrices. Matrix $A_0$ is a function of some parameters $x,y,z$. I create a new list of matrices, say $A_1$ produced by conjugating $A_0$ with all elements in $B$. Specifically,

```
A1[x_, y_, z_] = Table[B[[i]].A0[x, y, z].ConjugateTranspose[B[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[B]}] //Simplify // DeleteDuplicates;
```

Note that at the end I remove possible duplicate matrices in $A_1$.

From here I proceed in the same fashion, taking the new list of matrices $A_1$ and conjugating each element with each element in $B$, removing duplicates and obtaining a new list $A_2$

```
A2[x_, y_, z_] = Flatten[Table[B[[i]].A1[x, y, z][[j]].ConjugateTranspose[B[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[B]}, {j,1,Length[A1[x, y, z]]}],1] 
//Simplify // DeleteDuplicates;
```

Clearly this scales exponentially and at step $n$ I have to do $30^n$ matrix multiplications and then apply more operations on the list to remove the duplicates. In practice though, the non duplicate matrices after removing duplicates are something like ~(30,90,200,700,1500) for the first 5 iterations for my specific problem and lists of matrices. The problem is that after step 4 it takes a very long time to calculate in my computer. I suspect that this is mainly due to the use of `DeleteDuplicates` and I have seen that in simpler problems one can get an order of magnitude improvement if they use other ways to do the comparisons.

**Questions:**

1. Can I use a more clever and efficient way to delete the duplicates, instead of using the built-in function `DeleteDuplicates`?
2. I have tried to generalize my code so that I don't have to define every new step of iteration as a new block of code and defined an iterative function as follows:

```
iter[x_, y_, z_, 0] := 
  Table[B[[i]] . A0[x, y, z] . 
      ConjugateTranspose[B[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[B]}] //Simplify // DeleteDuplicates;
iter[x_, y_, z_, n_] := 
  Flatten[
     Table[
      B[[i]] . iter[x, y, z, n - 1][[j]] . ConjugateTranspose[B[[i]]], {i,
        1, Length[B]}, {j, 1, 
       Length[iter[x, y, z, n - 1]]}], 1] //Simplify // 
   DeleteDuplicates;
```

However, this doesn't seem to calculate beyond iterations 0 and 1. Or maybe it is way too slow? Any ideas how to do this properly?

3. If I define an iterative function as in Q2 and evaluate it, will it store previous values and only evaluate the new unknown ones or re-evaluate all function from scratch. That is, let's I have evaluated up to $n=1$ and call if for $n=2$ will it calculate again from scratch the values for $n=0,1$? If so, that would be clearly extremely inefficient.

**EDIT: Added matrices so that one can run the code**
I added the matrices straight after the first iteration.

```
A1[x_,y_,z_]={{{(1 + z)/2, 1/2 (x - I y)}, {1/2 (x + I y), (1 - z)/2}}, {{(1 - z)/
   2, 1/2 (x + I y)}, {1/2 (x - I y), (1 + z)/2}}, {{(1 - z)/2, 
   1/2 (-x - I y)}, {1/2 (-x + I y), (1 + z)/2}}, {{(1 + z)/2, 
   1/2 (-x + I y)}, {1/2 (-x - I y), (1 - z)/2}}, {{(1 + x)/2, 
   1/2 (-y + I z)}, {1/2 (-y - I z), (1 - x)/2}}, {{(1 + x)/2, 
   1/2 (y - I z)}, {1/2 (y + I z), (1 - x)/2}}, {{(1 - x)/2, 
   1/2 (-y - I z)}, {1/2 (-y + I z), (1 + x)/2}}, {{(1 - x)/2, 
   1/2 (y + I z)}, {1/2 (y - I z), (1 + x)/2}}, {{(1 - y)/2, 
   1/2 (I x + z)}, {1/2 (-I x + z), (1 + y)/2}}, {{(1 + y)/2, 
   1/2 I (x + I z)}, {-(1/2) I (x - I z), (1 - y)/2}}, {{(1 - y)/
   2, -(1/2) I (x - I z)}, {1/2 I (x + I z), (1 + y)/2}}, {{(1 + y)/2,
    1/2 (-I x + z)}, {1/2 (I x + z), (1 - y)/2}}, {{(1 + x)/2, 
   1/2 (I y + z)}, {1/2 (-I y + z), (1 - x)/2}}, {{(1 + x)/
   2, -(1/2) I (y - I z)}, {1/2 I (y + I z), (1 - x)/2}}, {{(1 - x)/2,
    1/2 I (y + I z)}, {-(1/2) I (y - I z), (1 + x)/2}}, {{(1 - x)/2, 
   1/2 (-I y + z)}, {1/2 (I y + z), (1 + x)/2}}, {{(1 - y)/2, 
   1/2 (x - I z)}, {1/2 (x + I z), (1 + y)/2}}, {{(1 + y)/2, 
   1/2 (x + I z)}, {1/2 (x - I z), (1 - y)/2}}, {{(1 - y)/2, 
   1/2 (-x + I z)}, {1/2 (-x - I z), (1 + y)/2}}, {{(1 + y)/2, 
   1/2 (-x - I z)}, {1/2 (-x + I z), (1 - y)/2}}, {{(1 + z)/
   2, -(1/2) I (x - I y)}, {1/2 I (x + I y), (1 - z)/2}}, {{(1 - z)/2,
    1/2 (-I x + y)}, {1/2 (I x + y), (1 + z)/2}}, {{(1 - z)/2, 
   1/2 I (x + I y)}, {-(1/2) I (x - I y), (1 + z)/2}}, {{(1 + z)/2, 
   1/2 (I x + y)}, {1/2 (-I x + y), (1 - z)/2}}};

B={{{1, 0}, {0, (-1)^(1/4)}}, {{0, (-1)^(1/4)}, {1, 
   0}}, {{0, -(-1)^(3/4)}, {I, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -(-1)^(1/4)}}, {{1/
   Sqrt[2], 1/2 + I/2}, {-(I/Sqrt[2]), -(1/2) + I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[2], 
   1/2 + I/2}, {I/Sqrt[2], 1/2 - I/2}}, {{I/Sqrt[2], 
   1/2 - I/2}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), -(1/2) - I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[
   2], -(1/2) - I/2}, {-(I/Sqrt[2]), 1/2 - I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[
   2], -(1/2) + I/2}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/2 - I/2}}, {{I/Sqrt[2], 
   1/2 + I/2}, {-(I/Sqrt[2]), 1/2 + I/2}}, {{-(1/Sqrt[2]), 
   1/2 - I/2}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/2 - I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[2], 1/2 - I/2}, {1/
   Sqrt[2], -(1/2) + I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[2], 1/2 + I/2}, {1/Sqrt[
   2], -(1/2) - I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[2], 1/2 + I/2}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 
   1/2 + I/2}}, {{I/Sqrt[2], 1/2 - I/2}, {-(I/Sqrt[2]), 
   1/2 - I/2}}, {{1/Sqrt[2], -(1/2) - I/2}, {1/Sqrt[2], 
   1/2 + I/2}}, {{1/2 - I/2, I/Sqrt[2]}, {1/2 + I/2, 1/Sqrt[
   2]}}, {{1/2 + I/2, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {1/2 - I/2, I/Sqrt[
   2]}}, {{-(1/2) + I/2, -(I/Sqrt[2])}, {1/2 + I/2, 1/Sqrt[
   2]}}, {{1/2 - I/2, -(I/Sqrt[2])}, {1/2 + I/2, -(1/Sqrt[2])}}, {{1, 
   0}, {0, (-1)^(3/4)}}, {{0, (-1)^(1/4)}, {I, 
   0}}, {{0, -(-1)^(3/4)}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -(-1)^(3/4)}}};
```

Comment: Very likely, `Simplify` is more of a bottleneck than `DeleteDuplicates`. However, having no input example, I cannot run it without guessing.

Comment: Would ```DeleteDuplicates``` understand if two matrices are the same but their form is slightly different? I suspect not, and this is why I used ```Simplify```, to put them in similar form.

Comment: I evn cannot imagine how your matrices look like. Do they have to be symbolic? Everything would be way faster if you could use matrices with floating point numbers

Comment: I added the matrices now, so the code should run

Comment: Yes, for my purposes they have to be symbolic. I know this is much slower but I can't avoid this at the moment.

Comment: Hm. Apparently, the entries in `A` are polynomials in `x`, `y`,` z`. You could try to use floating point numbers least for the coefficients. Then `Expand` should be able to take it quickly to a usable normal form. Or instead of `Expand` you could also try to use `CoefficientRules` to extract just the coefficients before you send everything to `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: For the example at hand, I use just the first element in the `A` list, and conjugate against all 24 elements in the `B` list. That gives 25 distinct matrices. Repeating this gives 231 distinct matrices (of 625 candidates). Is that the expected result? If so, I can show one way to proceed that might not be too onerous.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Thank you for your comment. I tried your approach but I am not sure I am doing this properly and so I end up with more matrices than when I do it symbolically. Could you elaborate or post it as an answer if you think this is going to help?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you but I need to conjugate all elements in A1 by elements in B that I provided. Also, how is it possible that conjugating one element with 24 elements you end up with 25? Shouldn't it be 24? In any case, the main issue is that the size of my list scales exponentially (at least before removing duplicates) and so I am trying to squeeze out a few iterations by improving the efficiency of my code. I suspect that I can save a lot of time by improving the performance of ```DeleteDuplicates``` and thus my question. If you have any ideas please expand or post as answer. Thanks

Comment: Original +24 conjugates gives 25…

Comment: In theory yes but i thought that one was the identity so it should be at most 24 but I need to double check, could be mistaken. @DanielLichtblau

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the dimension of the matrix class. The fastest way of deleting without deleting for small matrices is to use Union. The EqualTest may be streamlined eg by comparing simple features like first element or the trace. Instead of appending the latest entry use Union.

For very big matrices its probably faster to convert them to images by
Image@Raster@matrix.

For very very big arrays it may be even faster to make the EqualTest on ImageResize'ed objects.

Image processing has the most alaborated mechanisms for simple operations on large arrays

An example

```
img1 = Image@  Raster@
(ar1 = Array[({Sin[#1/24]^6 RandomReal[{0, 0.4}], 
         Sin[#2/12]^4 RandomReal[{0.4, 0.6}], 
         RandomReal[Sin[(#1 + #2)/12]^4 {0.2, 0.8}]} &), {1080, 
       1920}]).

ar2 = ReplacePart[ar1, {200, 200} -> {0, 0, 0}];
imge=Image@  Raster@ ar2

Timing[ar1 == ar2;]

Timing[img1==img2;]
```

Comment: I think there are some typos in your code (an extra "." and imge->img2). Apart from that, even though it is cool and I learned something new, I don't think it would be too useful in my case as my matrices are 2x2. Otherwise, can you look at the example I have provided and suggest an implementation?

Comment: I think this can't work, at least in its current form, because my A1 matrices depend on unspecified parameters $(x,y,z)$. Moreover, my matrices have complex elements in general.